# find the sum for the given function call in javascript

Tags: javascript

**sum(2)(3)(4)....(n)**

find the sum of n number of paranthas supplied with number as a arguments

I have tried

```
function sum (a){
    return function (b){
        return (a+b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what did you do here?

Comment: yes it should be like this  sum(2)(3)...(n)

Comment: actually this is related to javascript closure

Comment: Do you want a recursive function that adds all numbers up to n?

Comment: any sample input and output?

Comment: yes my code works for counted number of inputs but what to  do with n number of inputs ????

Comment: @vishalkumar : so then what the problem ?

Comment: You are looking for the term "currying".

Comment: for example : 
function sum (a){
    return function (b){
        return (a+b)
    }
}

sum(2)(3)

but now if i have some thing like this 
sum(2)(3)(4)....(n)
then what will be the code for it in javascript

Comment: @vishalkumar : there you go , read that

Comment: yes i think currying will solve the problem @Jonas  Thanks

Comment: thanks @MuhammadSalman

Comment: but apart from currying do we have a solution

Answer (score 0):

( I have to jet, will add explanation in a bit). But in a nutshell:

- As long as you have arguments you return a function that's keeping within it the sum and keeps adding each argument. I cheat and override `toString` of function to output the current value of `sum`.
- The fast way at the moment that I could think of not needing that `toString` is to just execute the function with an empty parameter and then not return a function but rather the `sum` value.

The bad thing? Well, overriding the `toString` you'll see in the `console.log()` might confuse users, since the actual type of what's returned is a function and not a number.

```js
var string_sum = sum(1)(1)(1);
console.log( string_sum + "  of type " + typeof(string_sum) );
var num_sum = sum(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)();
console.log( num_sum + " of type " + typeof(num_sum) );

function sum(x) {
  var sum = x;

  var sum_closure = function s(y){
     if ( y != undefined ){
      sum += y;
      return s;
     } else
      return sum;
  };
    
  if( ! Number.isInteger(sum_closure) )  
    Object.defineProperty(sum_closure, 'toString', {
          value: function () {
              return sum;
          }
      });
  
  return sum_closure;
}
```

Comment: check this i have got the solution
let add = (a) => {
  let sum = a;
  funct = function(b) {
    sum += b;
    return funct;
  };

  Object.defineProperty(funct, 'valueOf', {
    value: function() {
      return sum;
    }
  });
  return funct;
};


console.log(+add(1)(2)(3))